# Restitution only for specific objects in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody, restitution

I'm currently making a football (soccer) game using SpriteKit, but I've run into a little problem. When the characters (players) jump, I don't want them to bounce when they hit the ground after (that looks really weird and isn't very realistic).

Fine! Just set the restitution of the ground to zero!

But not so fast ... that means the ball won't bounce either.

Here are the important parts of my code:

```
struct cType {
    static let p1:UInt32 = 0
    static let ball:UInt32 = 1
    static let ground:UInt32 = 2
}
```

Moving on, in the `didMove(to view: SKView)` i define some properties of my objects:

```
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = cType.ball
ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = cType.p1 | cType.p2 | cType.ground
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = cType.p1 | cType.p2 | cType.ground

p1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = cType.p1
p1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = cType.p2 | cType.ball | cType.ground
p1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = cType.p2 | cType.ball | cType.ground
```

As for the collision detection itself, I just use the `didMove(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` and it works perfectly.

Now, of course I have a player 2 (`p2`), but that sprite has the exact same code as player 1 (`p1`) except `cType.p2` is changed to `cType.p1` and vice versa.

I also have some code `ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5` but this of course sets the restitution to 0.5 for any sprite who collides with the ground. This is where I'm really unsure. So my question is: How can I make sure the ball bounces when it hits the ground (with restitution 0.5), but my players (p1, p2) don't?

Comment: show your code where you create the physics for both players and the ball

Comment: I have now updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure how SpriteKit handles the collisions when objects with different restitution collide, but before getting to that you may have a problem with your categories.  They should all be nonzero (they're bitmasks), so what's with  `cType.p1=0`?  Usually you'd have bitmasks 1, 2, 4, 8, ...